# Java: Upload file from URL directly to FTP server with a library

Tags: java, url, upload, ftp, java-7

It is possible to transfer a file from a url (http://... .exe/ .zip ...) directly to a ftp server in Java 7 (with some additional libraries eg from Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is support for both HTTP and at least limited FTP support through the standard API class `java.net.URL`. You have only restricted access to specific FTP features like setting the transfer mode, but in most cases it works.

If you add Apache Commons IO, you can use the `IOUtils` class to copy directly from the HTTP server to the FTP server:

```
InputStream in = new URL("http://host/path").openStream();
OutputStream out = 
    new URL("ftp://user:pass@host/path").openConnection().getOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(in, out);

in.close();
out.close();
```

If you don't want to add a dependency on Commons IO, you just have to write a few lines to copy the data without 3rd party library support:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
int r = 0;
while ((r=in.read(buffer))>=0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible in general to instruct a web server to upload a file directly to an FTP server, but it's definitely possible to write a program to download the file yourself and then upload it to an FTP server.

Comment: so we need the additional step to store it locally on the computer after downloading from the url and then upload it? thought it is also possible to upload a file from a url directly

Comment: If you are in control of an FTP/web server, you could easily set up software on it so that you could remotely instruct it to *pull* from a given web server, but you can't instruct arbitrary web servers to upload to arbitrary FTP servers.

Comment: I dont want to instruct the web server. It should be possible to download using apache commons (io?) and net to transfer the file directly from an url to the ftp ... I just have access to the ftp server and want to write the small console application using java to transfer the file directly without downloading it locally and uploading

Comment: As far as I know, FTP and HTTP are completely separate protocols. To work with FTP, you need both a client and a server. An arbitrary HTTP server will not be able to communicate with your FTP server. If you have access to a server, why not just SSH into it and then `wget` whatever HTTP documents you'd like to download? Then you wouldn't need to write a program at all...

Comment: i have a server ;-) the java program uses apacha commons net and connects to the ftp server and uploads the files. I dont have ssh on this one.